# BGL: Remove vertex

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I am currently using

```
typedef boost::adjacency_matrix<boost::undirectedS, boost::no_property,boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int>> Graph;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
```

I am trying  to remove a Vertex from my graph by

```
int id = // Index that I associate the node with
boost::remove_vertex(Vertex(id),g);
```

However, this results in following error message

```
void boost::remove_vertex(typename boost::adjacency_matrix<D, VP, EP, GP, A>::vertex_descriptor, boost::adjacency_matrix<D, VP, EP, GP, A>&) [with D = boost::undirectedS; 
VP = boost::no_property; EP = boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int>; GP = boost::no_property; A = std::allocator<bool>; 
typename boost::adjacency_matrix<D, VP, EP, GP, A>::vertex_descriptor = long unsigned int]: Assertion `false' failed.
```

Can someone explain to me what that means? I suspect that I need to use some kind of proper indexing; until so far I simply used the values *0,1,...,n-1* to access my vertices. The value of *id* is definitely less than *num_vertices(g)*.

Comment: "Assertion \`false' failed." looks like somebody wrote somewhere an `assert(false);`. No idea why, but there might be a reason for this. I write `assert(false);` at locations where I never expect to run over - except I did something wrong. E.g. if I write a `switch()` for an `enum` which must handle all possible values, I add an `default: assert(false);` which hopefully reminds me to add the resp. `case` whenever I extended the corresponding `enum`.

Comment: Maybe, `boost::remove_vertex()` is just not supported. I came to this idea scrolling around in the doc. So, I ended up on [boots graph - adjacency_matrix](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_matrix.html). There, I found `remove_edge()` and `clear_vertex()` but not `remove_vertex()`. Considering that removal of a vertex results in modification of the whole matrix... (IMHO, this could make sense.)

Comment: ... That's the other reason why I might write `assert(false);` into my code - as reminder for something which is not yet implemented or even is not intended to be implemented.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat wouldn't assert(false) only work in debug runs and not release runs where NDEBUG is defined? Is there a hack to get such "assert" in release runs? Usually I have a printf, getchar followed by exit, but clearly something shorter would be highly beneficial.

Comment: @Tryer Correct - `assert()` expands to no-op if `NDEBUG` is defined. `assert()` is IMHO something intended to support development. If a condition has to be checked always just an `if` should be sufficient. As the `assert()` calls `abort()` if it's condition is false users probably won't like it.